# Transfer domain fails due to Extensible Provisioning Protocol (EPP)

Tags: domains, domain-registrar, domain-transfer

So I'm trying to transfer the hosting for a domain from Biz.nf to Bluehost. The domain was originally registered with Biz.nf. The domain is unlocked, and so is ready to transfer. However, I need the EPP, and that is where the problem comes in. For whatever reason, the current domain registrar is Wild West Domains (GoDaddy), despite the fact that I have never dealt with them. How exactly did this happen, and what can I do to get the EPP.

Comment: I cannot tell you for sure, but there are a lot of re-sellers out there for registrars. This means that the re-seller does not have to comply with the larger requirements that a registrar has to comply with in order to sell domain names. It is a lower point of entry into the domain sales market. This is not to be confuse with affiliates which tend to be transparent. So it is possible that the domain was purchased through a re-seller which can, for all intensive purposes, look like a registrar.

Comment: Are you a customer of Biz.nf?

Comment: You shouldn't need to change the registrar just to change hosting.   Hosting changes can be made by changing your DNS entries.   You don't need to switch registrars to edit DNS (or even to specify DNS servers).

Comment: You do not need "the EPP" as that makes no sense since EPP is a protocol used for exchange between registrars and registries. You need the `authInfo` which is a field specified by EPP to be associated with a domain (or a contact in fact) ant that is also often referenced as "authcode" or "domain password". This is the information needed to start a transfer at most TLDs.

Answer (score 1):

The reseller account holder -- the person who has an account with Biz.nf -- will need to contact them to get the required codes.  Once you have that code, you can then proceed with the transfer.

If the Biz.nf account holder is no longer available, some resellers will send the codes to the email listed on the whois records.  If you are this person/entity, you may be able to contact them and have them send the codes.

You may have to verify your identity.